# How scrapy crawl work:which class instanced and which method called?

Tags: scrapy

Here is a simple python file--test.py.

```
import math
class myClass():
    def myFun(self,x):
        return(math.sqrt(x))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    myInstance=myClass()
    print(myInstance.myFun(9))
```

It print 3 with `python  test.py`,let's analyse the running process.
1. to instance myClass and assign it to myInstance.
2.to call myFun function and print the result.

It is scrapy's turn.
In the scrapy1.4 manual,quotes_spider.py is as below.

```
import scrapy 

class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "quotes"

    def start_requests(self):
        urls = [
            'http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/1/',
            'http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/2/',
        ]
        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        page = response.url.split("/")[-2]
        filename = 'quotes-%s.html' % page
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.body)
        self.log('Saved file %s' % filename)
```

To run the spider with `scrapy crawl quotes`,i am puzzled:
1.Where is the main function or main body for the spider?
2.Which class was instanced?
3.Which method was called?

```
mySpider = QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider)
mySpider.parse(response)
```

How scrapy crawl  work exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So let's start. Assuming you use linux/mac. Let's check where us scrapy

```
$ which scrapy
/Users/tarun.lalwani/.virtualenvs/myproject/bin/scrapy
```

Let's look at the content of this file

```
$ cat /Users/tarun.lalwani/.virtualenvs/myproject/bin/scrapy
#!/Users/tarun.lalwani/.virtualenvs/myproject/bin/python3.6

# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
import sys

from scrapy.cmdline import execute

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.argv[0] = re.sub(r'(-script\.pyw?|\.exe)?$', '', sys.argv[0])
    sys.exit(execute())
```

So this executes `execute` method from `cmdline.py` and her is your main method.

**cmdline.py**

```
from __future__ import print_function
....
....

def execute(argv=None, settings=None):
    if argv is None:
        argv = sys.argv

    # --- backwards compatibility for scrapy.conf.settings singleton ---
    if settings is None and 'scrapy.conf' in sys.modules:
        from scrapy import conf
        if hasattr(conf, 'settings'):
            settings = conf.settings
    # ------------------------------------------------------------------

    if settings is None:
        settings = get_project_settings()
        # set EDITOR from environment if available
        try:
            editor = os.environ['EDITOR']
        except KeyError: pass
        else:
            settings['EDITOR'] = editor
    check_deprecated_settings(settings)

    # --- backwards compatibility for scrapy.conf.settings singleton ---
    import warnings
    from scrapy.exceptions import ScrapyDeprecationWarning
    with warnings.catch_warnings():
        warnings.simplefilter("ignore", ScrapyDeprecationWarning)
        from scrapy import conf
        conf.settings = settings
    # ------------------------------------------------------------------

    inproject = inside_project()
    cmds = _get_commands_dict(settings, inproject)
    cmdname = _pop_command_name(argv)
    parser = optparse.OptionParser(formatter=optparse.TitledHelpFormatter(), \
        conflict_handler='resolve')
    if not cmdname:
        _print_commands(settings, inproject)
        sys.exit(0)
    elif cmdname not in cmds:
        _print_unknown_command(settings, cmdname, inproject)
        sys.exit(2)

    cmd = cmds[cmdname]
    parser.usage = "scrapy %s %s" % (cmdname, cmd.syntax())
    parser.description = cmd.long_desc()
    settings.setdict(cmd.default_settings, priority='command')
    cmd.settings = settings
    cmd.add_options(parser)
    opts, args = parser.parse_args(args=argv[1:])
    _run_print_help(parser, cmd.process_options, args, opts)

    cmd.crawler_process = CrawlerProcess(settings)
    _run_print_help(parser, _run_command, cmd, args, opts)
    sys.exit(cmd.exitcode)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    execute()
```

Now if you notice execute method it processes the arguments passed by you. which is `crawl quotes` in your case. The execute methods scans the projects for classes and check which has name defined as `quotes`. It creates the `CrawlerProcess` class and that runs the whole show.

[image: Scrapy Architecture]

Scrapy is based on Twisted Python Framework. Which is a scheduler based framework.

Consider the below part of the code

```
 for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)
```

When the engine executes this function and first yield is execute. The value is returned to the engined. The engine now looks at other task that are pending executes them, (when they yield, some other pending task queue function gets a chance). So `yield` is what allows to break a function execution into parts and help Scrapy/Twisted work.

You can get a detailed overview on the link below

https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/architecture.html